# executable with parameters with quotes

Tags: powershell, parameters

I'm trying to replace an old CMD script with a PowerShell script. The batch script calls an exe and sends two parameters (one is quotes).

Example: `executable.exe %parameter1% "%paramter2%"`

I have my PowerShell with all the variables I need. The last part is calling the executable with the paramters.

```
c:\executable.exe $parameter1 "$parameter2"
```

This is all pseudocode, I also know when using quotes in PowerShell it will display the parameter literal.

How can I call an executable in PowerShell and give one parameter that is a variable and second parameter als variable in quotes and all should be passed as 1 line.

P.S: I tried the `& call` method, but maybe I did something wrong.

Comment: try '"%paramter2%"'

Comment: `c:\executable.exe $parameter1 "$parameter2"` or `& c:\executable.exe $parameter1 "$parameter2"` should already do what you want. If it doesn't you need to describe the actual problem you're facing, not some pseudocode.

Comment: @guiwhatsthat it didnt work.

Comment: @AnsgarWiechers I will post the real code tommorow and what i'm trying to accomplice.

Comment: @ilyasseB. the backtick is used as an escape character, you should be able to use the backtick before the quotation marks to ensure that the quotes are passed to the executable.  I'd also use the "Start-Process" cmdlet with a splatted argument list.  `$args = @($parameter1, `"$parameter2`")`  and on line 2 `Start-Process C:\executable.exe -ArgumentList $args`

Comment: Well - the formatting gets messed up here but the point remains.